# JENKINS subversion URL clipped

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

I am using JENKINS to configure a build process of a project.

While configuring the project from JENKINS GUI, I tried to enter the URL of my repository.

Like https://abc.xyz.def.rst.com/jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/

I get exception as below.

NOTES :

1. Jenkins has been deployed on a UNIX machine.
2. JENKINS GUI is being accessed from WINDOWS:
3. The repository can be accessed using SVN commands from the UNIX machine.

   ```
   FAILED: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/ failed


   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS /jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/ failed
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:291)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:276)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:264)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:97)
       at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1790)
       at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1735)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:104)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:234)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)
       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:159)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
       at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:249)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:335)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:378)
       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
       at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
       at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
       at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
       at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
       at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
       at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
       at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
       at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
       at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)
       at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
   Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/ failed
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
       ... 49 more
   Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/'
   svn: timed out waiting for server
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:644)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:285)
       ... 48 more
   Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/jkl/bnm/branches/myApp/'
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:642)
       ... 49 more
   Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: timed out waiting for server
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:394)
       ... 49 more
   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:520)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:545)
       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketConnection.run(SVNSocketConnection.java:57)
       ... 1 more
   ```

   As you can see the URL has been clipped which is why Jenkins is not able to connect to the repo.

   Please help.

Comment: Is there a tiny, hidden space in there after the '.com'?

Comment: No. There is no space in between anywhere.

Comment: Sorry. That was a dumb question. This one is better. Have you verified that you can access SVN from the Jenkins machine when logged in as the Jenkins user? I think the SVN OPTIONS is a read request.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `SVN OPTIONS` is a read but your problem could be something else.

Check the webserver logs on the svn server - since you're using https I am certain that svn is configured to work oven a web server (apache or nginx) and I suppose that is Apache. :)

You will find more information in those logs.

Then check the permissions for the jenkins user on the svn - to the SVN server Jenkins looks like any other user and if there is no read right you will not be able to connect.

Since the JAVA package starts with `org.tmatesoft.svn.` this means that you're using svnKit on the server to connect to the SVN server. Check how Jenkins handles this connection interface - support may be incomplete. JavaHL is an alternative.